# Почему входная строка имела неверный формат, если ещё не было ничего введено?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

При входе в функцию сразу выбрасывается исключение System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат." , хотя я даже ничего не вводил ещё

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите номер лабораторной работы: ");
            int numLab = Console.Read();

            switch (numLab)
                {
                    case 49: Lab1(); break;
                    case 50: Lab2(); break;
                    //case 51: Lab3(); break;

                    default: Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод!"); break;
                }
        }

 private static void Lab2()
        {
            double y = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите значение аргумента X: ");
            string buf = Console.ReadLine();
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(buf);

            if (x >= -7 || x <= 4)
            {
                if (x == -7) y = 0;
                else if (x == 0) y = 0;
                else if (x == 2) y = 4;
                else if (x == 4) y = 0;

                else if (x > -7 && x < -3) y = x + 7;
                else if (x >= -3 && x <= -2) y = 4;
                else if (x > -2 && x < 2) y = Math.Pow(x, 2);
                else if (x > 2 && x < 4) y = 2 * x + 8;

            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Значения вне диапазона графика!");

            Console.WriteLine("Значение функции Y: " + y);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Исключение выбрасывает какой-то другой код.

Comment: Перед `double x = Convert.ToDouble(buf);` добавьте: `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("buf=[{0}]", buf));Console.ReadKey();` - что вывелось в консоль?

Comment: @Igor, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: что вывелось в консоль?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полную информацию об исключении, включая stack trace.

Comment: Приведите код, в который вызывается ваш метод. В коде метода проблемы нет, а вот в вызывающем коде похоже вполне типичная ошибка.

Comment: Потому что пустая строка не парсится в дабл. Должно быть введено число. Это распространенная ошибка начинающих

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка довольно типичная и распространенная у новичков.

Простой пример:

```
Console.Read();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Этот код, с виду, должен дважды запросить ввод значений (не важно, что мы ни куда их не записываем), однако на практике вы сможете ввести только одно значение - один раз нажать на <kbd>Enter</kbd> после ввода любого непустого набора символов.

Причина в особенностях работы методов `Read` и `ReadLine`.

- если входной поток пуст - оба метода начинают ожидание ввода от пользователя.
- в противном случае чтение происходит без ожидания.

`Read` читает ровно один символ, `ReadLine` читает до конца строки, но делают они это только после того, как пользователь нажмет <kbd>Enter</kbd> для подтверждения окончания ввода. Нажатие на <kbd>Enter</kbd> в свою очередь добавит во входной поток признак конца строки.

Таким образом, если после вызова оператора `Console.Read` (последнего, если он используется многократно для посимвольного чтения) не дочитать входной поток до конца, например вызовом `Console.ReadLine()` без сохранения результата, то при следующем вызове любого из этих методов вы автоматически прочитаете хвост от предыдущего ввода. Собственно именно это и происходит в вашем коде.

Решение, как не сложно догадаться, найти где перед вызовом вашего метода используется `Console.Read` и <strike>обезвредить</strike> дочитать хвост.